# What set do these pieces belong to?

Tags: set-identification, piece-information

Black pieces rotate, if it helps?
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 12):

Having checked various different parts (including severely underestimating how widespread [Trans-Light Blue Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3941&colorID=15&in=A) is) I believe that this may be [LEGO Friends: Pop Star Show Stage](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=41105-1), based on [Bright Light Orange Plate, Round 4 x 4 with Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60474&colorID=110&in=A), which only appeared in 10 sets

[image: Image of a 3-part LEGO Pop Stage, with moving spotlights controlled by the axels]